# T-SQL: calculate in dependence of the content of a column

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql

I want to calculate in T-SQL in dependence of the content of a column, the content of another column should be in the numerator or denominator

I have a table with the following content:

```
+------------+----------+----+-------------------------+  
| machine-nr | duration | ID | timestamp               |  
+------------+----------+----+-------------------------+  
| 1108       | 47       | 11 | 2017-02-11 00:08:15.000 |  
| 1112       | 195      | 2  | 2017-02-11 00:13:13.000 |  
| 1108       | 339      | 7  | 2017-02-11 00:13:54.000 |  
| 1108       | 19       | 2  | 2017-02-11 00:13:54.000 |  
| 1112       | 20       | 11 | 2017-02-11 00:13:33.000 |  
+------------+----------+----+-------------------------+
```

Now I want to do this sort of calculation

Every duration with the ID 11 should be in the dividend and the sum of all duration with the IDs 11, 2 and 7 should be in the divisor.

Something like that (i know it doesn't work that way):

```
SUM(duration if ID = 11) / SUM(duration if ID =11) + SUM(duration if ID = 2) + SUM(Duration if ID = 7)
group by machine-nr
```

I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: `tsql` is not `mysql` ... then why both tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select machine_nr, 
       sum(case when id = 11 then duration end) 
         / sum(case when id in (11,2,7) then duration end) as end_calc
from MyTable
group by machine_nr
```